# Escaping backslash in regex in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a regex to match `_text_` but to not match `\_text\_` as `[^\\_]_(.)*[^\\_]_`
This seems to work on the online RegExr parsing tool. My attempt to make it as an NSString is not working. I have this: `@"[^\\\\_]_(.)*[^\\\\_]_"`

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The string you provided works for me, but should't the negated set at the start of the expression have a "*" quantifier?

```
NSString *goodString = @"_text_";
NSString *badString = @"\\_text\\_";
NSError *error;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^\\\\_]*_(.)*[^\\\\_]_"
                              options:0
                              error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@ - %lu", goodString, (unsigned long)[regex numberOfMatchesInString:goodString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, goodString.length)]);
NSLog(@"%@ - %lu", badString, (unsigned long)[regex numberOfMatchesInString:badString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, badString.length)]);
```

Result:

```
_text_ - 1
\_text\_ - 0
```

Comment: There's something funky going on because the input has to `\_text\_` and the escape characters are messing it up. Your suggestion doesn't work either for me.